How to fix Git Error "RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22" permanently?
I’ve been using Git for my project for a year without issues, but now I'm constantly getting this error when I try to push: "RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400 send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet."
I know that if I use git config http.postBuffer 524288000 and then run git pull && git push, it works (for a while).
But I’d like to permanently fix the problem. Does anyone know how?

What do you mean "works for a while"? When does it stop working? Did you try to set the config value global for all repositories? git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000 ?

In the past few days, I encountered the issue again when I tried to pull. Since I work with several repositories at the same time, I didn't know if it was the same repo causing the issue again. Maybe if I set it globally for all repositories, I won't have this issue anymore. Thanks, I’ll try that.

This question is similar to: Git error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400 send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

TL;DR: your connection is timing out. What are you pushing and pulling?

This error often occurs due to issues with the buffer size Git uses for HTTP operations.
Increase the HTTP post buffer size:
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

This command increases the buffer size to 150 MB, which can help if you’re pushing large files12.

Santa maria! worked like magic <3

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/241999/the-muslims-are-closer-to-maryam-the-daughter-of-imraan-than-the-christians

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/10277/jesus-in-islam
